# Normalized interpolation doesn't work for WGS84

Tags: python, interpolation, shapely

I am trying to interpolate linestring on WGS84 coordinate system by factor 0.5.
LineString length is 427 meters (measured by different tools), so I expect to get line with length=213.5 meters. But I get 227 meters. Is that well-known problem?

```
import shapely.wkt
line1 = 'LINESTRING (-0.13339 51.51013, -0.13109 51.5077, -0.132505 51.507191)'
l1 = shapely.wkt.loads(line1)
start_pt = l1.interpolate(0.5, normalized=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to measure distances in lat-long, as a degree of longitude is not the same ground length (in meters) as a degree of latitude.

The linestring has 3 points that are not aligned. The first (top) half of the linestring vary a bit in longitude and a lot in latitude. The second (bottom) half of the linestring vary much more in longitude than in latitude. In terms of distances, both half have the same length **in degrees**, and once converted to meters, taking into consideration the difference in ground length (in m) of a degree of longitude vs latitude, you end up with different lengths **in meters**.

To fix this issue, you can project your data to a suitable coordinate system that uses meters, such as UTM.